# A statistical test to evaluate two non-normally distributed groups without same shape distribution with different sample sizes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, python

I want to compare two populations that are:

- Not normally distributed,
- Do not follow the same distribution shape,
- Have different sample sizes.

Is there any test which corresponds to these requirements? I have been looking into non-parametric tests, but all seem to either require the data to follow the same distribution shape, or have the same sample size.

Comment: What aspect of the distributions do you want to compare? Means? Medians? CDFs?

Comment: Which nonparametric tests did you find that require the same sample size? // @COOLSerdash has the right idea. What do you want to compare?

Comment: Are your measurements paired (dependent) or unpaired (independent)?

Comment: Why do you want to compare these distributions?

Comment: @CooLSerdash I want to compare the means

Comment: @Dave The test with the same sample size was the Wilcoxon for example.

Comment: @Alexis the measurements are unpaired so independent

Comment: @BigBendRegion They are male and female data, and I want to see whether there are significant differences between them. However, the original researchers only had 10 women compared to 22 men

Comment: The Wilcoxon (Mann-Whitney U) test has no requirement that the groups have the same size.

Comment: @Dave: The Wilcoxon signed rank test requires same sized groups, and the Mann-Whitney U test requires both groups to have the same shape

Comment: Mann-Whitney U does not require same-shape distributions. It only requires that for the interpretation to be about a shift in the location while leaving alone the rest of the distribution e.g., N(0,1) to N(1,1). That interpretation allows you to make the conclusion you want to make about the means, but when the distribution shapes are markedly different, wondering about a difference in means strikes me as unhelpful, given the many other differences. After all, N(1,1) and exp(1) have the same mean (and variance), yet those are pretty different distributions!

Comment: As you may have realized by now, it is possible to speculate endlessly--without specific information about your data. Can you show sample sizes, data summaries, histograms, or boxplots of your data and be more specific about your goals?

Comment: @Michiel Well you already said there were differences in the distributions, so your job is done. No need for a test when you already know.